# How can I move or request the move of a documentation example to a different topic?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics

How can I move (or request the move) of a documentation example to a more appropriate topic?

Related questions appear to rely on early-beta functionality that is no longer present.

Comment: Click on `edit` on the topic or on a specific example.  Then, click on `move` or `move example`.  From there, you can choose which examples to move, and then choose the destination topic.